# Can an Android Spyware hide from App List?

Tags: android, virus, malware, spyware

Is possible to any harmful software to be installed on Android, without the user's permission and hide that software in the App List?

Spyware, virus, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to have an app with no launcher icon, but every app will show up in the Settings's Application list.

Additionally, starting with Android 3.1, applications aren't allowed to do anything at all until they have been started by the user at least once, which requires them to be present in the launcher.